# Issues with passing functions and variables

Tags: list, variables, python-2.6

I posted a few days ago about a black jack game I'm trying to build...making some progress! But when I get to trying to simulate what a deal looks like and modifying the deck, I'm not able to print the modified deck.

```
import random 

suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']


def deck_func():
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append((rank, suit))
    return deck

def deal(deck_func):
    card_dealt = random.choice(deck_func())
    return card_dealt

def dealt_deck(deck_func, deal):
    card_deck = deck_func()
    new_deck = card_deck.remove(deal(deck_func))
    return new_deck

print deal(deck_func)
print dealt_deck(deck_func, deal)
```

I get the following as the printed functions...

```
('King', 'clubs')
None
```

And I can't figure out why.  The card list is being created...but the new deck isn't for some reason.  Another weird issue...if I put 'print deck_func()' before the other print functions, the other functions don't even fire...why is that??

Help!  And thank you!

Comment: The ``.remove()`` method of lists *does not return anything* - that is the general behavior in Python for functions that modify their parameter in-place.  You should just ``return card_deck`` instead.

Comment: Is there a better method than .remove()?  I tried filter...but that didn't seem to work either, but I probably implemented it wrong.

Comment: ``.remove()`` does exactly what you appear to want, you just need to not try to use its return value (since it doesn't have one).

Comment: So how would I call the modified list then...?  I thought that's what return would have done...

Comment: The modified list is called ``card_deck``; ``.remove()`` does not create a new list, it modifies an existing one.

Comment: So, 'return' works for operations, like multiplications, etc?  What is the .remove() classified as?